# What kind of handheld device/OS to use to interface with a Win Forms/ SQL Server Express App?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, mobile, handheld

I'm currently working on an VB.net application using Win forms and SQL Server Express 2008. One of the major functions of our program is to generate work orders for field engineers. These engineers typically work in a factory and have to walk around the factory to complete these work orders doing things such as recording pressures and voltages of certain equipment. Right now they are printing out the work orders and writing down these values then entering them into the computer when they get back from doing the work. We would like them to have some sort of handheld device we could push their work orders out to that would allow them to enter values/complete work orders and then come back and sync up with our app. Something like an ipod touch or maybe a bit larger seems like a good kind of device. Not really sure what kind of device would work for this and what OS it should run. I'm guessing it will be easiest if I can get something that can run SQL server on it. Also, how would I implement something like this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there a WiFi network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My company writes software that tracks emergency event information which implements handhelds in a similar fashion.  The software we finally decided on was [ITScriptnet](http://www.z-space.com/) and ITOmniScript, which is a programming language designed for hand helds that automates synchronizing, and database communication with any hand held device.

Pro's:

1. It also works well with any brand of hand held, so you can write one set of code without worrying about which DLL goes to which handheld's scanner or buttons or w/e making your software very platform independent.
2. Efficiently manages offline/online data transfer
3. Represents databases on handhelds using text files (similar to CSV style)
4. They have a sample download I believe you can try, its limitation is that you can only synch 10 records at a time until you buy the full $100 license.
5. GPS aware

Con's:

1. $100 per license for each hand held on top of the cost of the handheld
2. A different programming language (it has .NET qualities and some .NET calls, but is really quite different)
3. Configuring the OmniServer to talk with the handhelds can sometimes be a pain, but we've gotten it to work so far (installed 50+ probably of these systems).

If you don't like that technology, then you'll likely want to go with the Compact Framework, then you have to find a handheld that will run CE code, and write specific code to that unit (which may or may not work partially or fully on another CE device).  I've written this code as well, and while its not difficult, its also very limited.  I've also heard that some of the new "Windows 7 Handhelds" are going to be able to run SQL Express compact edition.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to OS it will be the easiest way to use some version of WinMobile OS ("CE",WIN )
Most of industry equipment that I have seen was on WinMobile OS (There also was DOS terminals but it is past tense now).
At manufacturers side there is DataLogic, Psion Teklogix introduces , Symbol, Honeywell and others.
Why I suggesting you WinMobile it is because SQL Server Compact edition which easy works on WinMobile devices and also there is Compact framework which can use most of your already written  VB code.

*Another approach that at our company was taken in one businesses process was:*
Sample Compact Web application written for SmartDevices, Compact displays and easy fill forms.
Here some pros:
With WEB application you art not sticked to some Device, even OS, (most of devices today have Web Browsers with JavaScrip enabled inside, that could be enough for sample application for inputing data to forms);
Online entering data and no need for another synchronization
And there is also cons:
User always must be online,
If you planing to use BarcodeScaner you interface can only be keyboard (a lot of devices do not need
additional drivers for caching data from barcode they already act as keyboard, sometime that is not fact)
*Third solution and to me most adoptable is:*
Some kind of mini laptops with GSM terminals and Wlan cards.
We are using a lot of them for inventory process at out shops.
Here is pros:
Today Mini laptop such as (Acer Aspire One) are cheaper 2X times then any terminals on market.
You are comfort to run any OS on it (XP, Vista, Unbuntu and others).
When device not using application there is much more things to do than SmartDevice/ Terminal.
Large displays with lot of data

Here is cons:
Not so ergonomics and sometimes hard and slow to use (no numeric keyboard, Barcode scanner must be wired and handled by other hand).
Not for heavy condition as low temperatures and dust